# Reverse Frames in Sprite Sheet - Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

How do i reverse the frames of an sprite sheet with each frame of size 30x30 and horizontally aligned using Imagemagick?

Example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIoYc.png ->>> https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WR9v.png (edited)

Comment: Are there always just two? Do you mean to reverse the order or to flip the entire sheet left to right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that like this...

First, create three little 30x30 images in Red, Green and Blue:

```
convert -size 30x30! xc:red red.png
convert -size 30x30! xc:green green.png
convert -size 30x30! xc:blue blue.png
```

then append them side by side:

```
convert +append red.png green.png blue.png image.png
```

to get this:

[image]

Now crop that into 30x30 pixel frames, and reverse the order of the frames, then re-append them together into the output image.

```
convert -crop 30x30 image.png -reverse +append out.png
```

[image]

**Note:**

For future reference, if anyone wants to do the same thing but vertically instead of horizontally, just change `+append` to `-append`.